# Can a Xamarin.IOS with PushSharp app be rejected by Apple AppStore?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am designing a project that will use **Xamarin.iOS** for creating an iPhone/iPad application, which will make use of push notifications and in the end, it has to be published to **Apple AppStore**.
While I have to use Xamarin.iOS, I know that push notifications are done by using the  [PushSharp library](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp).
Having in mind the constraints that Apple impose for publishing an app in their store, especially these points:

- **2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected**
- **5.1 Apps that provide Push Notifications without using the Apple Push Notification (APN) API will be
  rejected**

So, will using **PushSharp** library to send push notifications to iOS devices, cause my app to be rejected by Apple?

Answer (score 2):

No, because PushSharp only uses public libraries, and it uses Apples system to send notifications. So, Apple will have no problem with your app if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Xamarin creates C# wrappers for any private methods so I don't think you have to worry about that. Under the hood, I'm pretty sure that @redth uses the native push services for each platform. Also, doesn't PushSharp 'run' on your server not your ios app? This shouldn't affect your app anyway.